# Can you replicate Android Stock Camera rotation in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, android-orientation

I've tried to replicate android's stock camera rotation in flutter but to no success. Either the whole app rotates, or nothing rotates. I tried to also dig deeper into the native code, but couldn't find anything that keeps the app static, while the whole system rotates behind the scenes. The main thing I am looking for is to keep the Camera view static (landscape mode), and rotate the UI with the system depending on the device orientation.

Comment: There might be better solutions but using [OrientationBuilder](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/orientation) you can have two separate `layouts` which will be switched when user changes device orientation. You can keep the `layout` for camera view same in both orientations and customize the other parts. Also check medium article on `OrientationBuilder`.